# Using PHP mail() URL encodes links in recipients mailboxes

Tags: php, email, urlencode

I am using the PHP `mail()` function to send out automated emails from my site but one particular link I want to send has a PHP query at the end.

Like this: `page.php?foo=bar`

However, when it is sent and the recipient gets the email, the link has now become URL encoded.

Like this: `page.php?foo%3Dbar`

I know that `=` is a reserved character for URLs, but how can I get around this?

Comment: I didn't think this would work but thought it was worth a try. I used `&#61;` instead of `=` but it still came out the other end as `%3D`.